# How to search and display XML file in browser

Tags: asp.net, xml, search, vbscript

I'm looking for ways to display XML file in browser by using asp.net method.

Below is the code that I'm using to search for any .XML file with the word "verify" as its title.

Now, I'm just wondering if there is a way to display the XML file in the web browser.

```
Protected Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click


    'To find subdirectories with a specific pattern/WILD CARD
    'ms-help://MS.VSExpressCC.v80/MS.NETFramework.v20.en/dv_vbcn/html/c9265fd1-7483-4150-8b7f-ff642caa939d.htm
    'Me.ListBox1.Items.Clear()
    Dim path As String = "\\g1w6223c\e$"
    Dim searchPattern As String = "*verify*.xml"
    For Each value As String In My.Computer.FileSystem.GetFiles(path, FileIO.SearchOption.SearchAllSubDirectories, searchPattern
                                                                )
        ListBox1.Items.Add(value)
        TextBox1.Text = "found"
    Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Microsoft® Internet Explorer to view XML documents in the browser, just as you would view HTML pages. Unlike HTML, XML does not predefine display properties for specific elements. Therefore, XML requires a separate style sheet that specifies how the XML data should be displayed. This separation of XML content from its presentation allows the content to be easily repurposed.
To view an XML file in Internet Explorer, you can specify a style sheet the following ways.
Use the default style sheet, which presents the file as a collapsible tree.
Specify a specific style sheet at the top of the XML file, in an href attribute such as the following:

Specify any style sheet at the command prompt, for example:
c:\bat\msxsl mydata.xml mytransform.xsl -o myoutput.html